# Trying to update the UI WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Inside my WPF application I have this code in my Demo_click event:
cmdDoMyThing is a ToggleButton

```
cmdDoMyThing.IsChecked = True
cmdDoMyThing.UpdateLayout()
Delay()
showAnotherDialog()
cmdDoMyThing.IsChecked = False
```

This is the Delay()

```
Sub Delay()
    Thread.Sleep(2000)
End Sub
```

And my problem is that I want to update the UI inside the Demo_Click event, before this method finish. So the cmdDoMyThing is checked and display the state checked in the UI, then wait for 2 seconds, call the showAnotherDialog and when the user close the showAnotherDialog then cmdDoMyThing is unchecked, update the UI and continue the process inside the Demo_click event.
I am like crazy trying to make it work and I cannot find the way to do it.
Any suggestion? thank you in advance.

Comment: Dude, I'd advise you to take a good look through the [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx) pages on MSDN... you seem to be really confused about how to use it... it's *not* WinForms.

Comment: You do not need to use the `Call` keyword anymore!

Comment: +1 for _it's not WinForms_, it most certainly isn't!

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, I know it is not forms, and I am asking for some guidance on my problem.
Please focus on behavior of the UI :)

Comment: Take a look at using the `Dispatcher` instead of `Thread.Sleep`. I actually have [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930792/302677) on here that may help in understanding the Dispatcher and how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, i think you are looking for a modal window/dialog. Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) method when opening your dialog instead of show

Comment: May be I don't explain very well my issue. It is not a problem to show the dialog. I have to replicate this behavior:
Show the ToggleButton clicked, wait 2 secs, show the dialog, uncheck the ToggleButton, wait 2 secs, and do another thing. But all this inside the same method. The problem is that the UI looks like don't refresh when I need it.
Thank you for the comment :)