# Bound property not always updated to the control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have the following code in my view model. It's got three different states and the thing that puzzles me is that the first and last state are shown in the control but the progressing doesn't.

```
public void DoStuffForAWhile(int limit)
{
  TheBoundProperty = "This is not shown.";

  DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
  TimeSpan elapsed;
  do
  {
    elapsed = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - start.Ticks);
    TheBoundProperty = "Neither is this.";
  } while (elapsed.TotalSeconds < limit);

  TheBoundProperty = "But this is!";
}
```

The binding is correctly set because I see the starting text as I create the view model. And I see the last text from the updater. Also, the set method of the property is hit and the value are the strings that aren't shown.

Any hints on why the values are not displayed? How to kill the problem?

Comment: You are updating the property too often and its updates are being lost.

Comment: @KonradViltersten your loop runs on UI thread and blocks it and the event raised by `TheBoundProperty` is not processed until it is able to do so. Run your long running task on background thread and raise property changed event via dispatcher

Comment: @Marko I'm not sure if you're right. I've tested to add delays but that didn't affect a thing. I suspect that it's got to do with what dkozl mentions.

Comment: @dkozl Suggestions on how to resolve it, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delay.

```
public async void DoStuffForAWhile(int limit)
{
  TheBoundProperty = "This is not shown.";

  DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
  TimeSpan elapsed;
  do
  {
    elapsed = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - start.Ticks);
    TheBoundProperty = "Neither is this.";
    await Task.Delay(1000); //1 sec delay
  } while (elapsed.TotalSeconds < limit);

  TheBoundProperty = "But this is!";
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you insist on using Task..

```
public async void Foo(int limit){
    await DoStuffForAWhile(limit);
    TheBoundProperty = "But this is!";
}

public async Task DoStuffForAWhile(int limit)
{
  TheBoundProperty = "This is not shown.";

  DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
  TimeSpan elapsed;
  do
  {
    elapsed = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - start.Ticks);
    TheBoundProperty = "Neither is this.";
    await Task.Delay(1000); //1 sec delay
  } while (elapsed.TotalSeconds < limit);
}
```

But it is completely unnecessary to use Task or the Dispatcher

Comment: Any comments how this code relates to the other reply? When I used yours, it resolved my problem but I'm afraid that I just hid the problem. Would you say that working with *async* and *await* is preferable to *Task*? Or rather - what are the upsides and downsides?

Comment: Simply you do not need to use a Task, use "async void" is to shoot and forget and that is what you need.

Comment: For dual suggestion +1.

Comment: The main thing to be careful of with this implementation is objects in WPF can only be modified on the thread they were created on, so you may have some trouble modifying or creating objects from within your `async` code. For something simple like `Task.Delay`, this is fine though.

Comment: TheBoundProperty = "Neither is this."; - This statement is executed on the thread that were the async operation was created - Unless explicitly a new thread is initialized, the current implementation does not present any problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is because all normal code runs at `DispatcherPriority.Normal` on the main UI thread, and all rendering code runs at `DispatcherPriority.Render`, which is lower on the [priority list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx).

Everything that runs at .Normal gets executed before anything on .Render, so by the time the UI updates only the final message is there.

What you want to do is set the string to loading, then start another thread to execute your long-running process. Once your long-running process completes, you want to update the label again.

I would expect your final code to look something like this :

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    TheBoundProperty = "Loading ..";

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        RunSomething();
    })
    .RunWorkerCompleted(() => 
    {
        TheBoundProperty = "Load Completed";
    });
}
```

If you want periodic updates, I'd expect something like this which uses the dispatcher to send updates to the main UI thread.

```
private void UpdateLoadingLabel(int percent)
{
    Application.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new Action(delegate() { 
         TheBoundProperty = string.Format("Loading {0}/100..", percent);
     }));
}
```

I'm not entirely sure I have the syntax for all this right, but you should get the idea. For a more detailed explanation on this sample code, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930792/302677).

Comment: Two questions to that. (1) You mean that the method *UpdateLoadingLabel* should be called from the progressing process on the other thread, right? (2) How would your suggestion relate to the other answer in this thread? I can't decide which is the most appropriate for me - his is shorter but yours seems more profound.

Comment: Yes, `UpdateLoadingLabel` would be called from the background thread. The main reason for using the Dispatcher here is that objects in WPF cannot be modified from a thread that they were not created on, so in order to update your loading label you need to send the call back to the main UI thread. The other answer is using `await`, which is a newer keyword that allows you to queue the following code on another thread without having to actually bother creating the task/thread. The main problem with it is if you have to update an item created on the main UI thread from within the awaitable code.