# How to use BackgroundWorker to show/hide WPF UI element?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have a rectangle which I want to make visible, then I want to wait for 500 milliseconds, then I want to make it invisible again.

Initially I tried this code:

```
MuzzleFlash.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
Thread.Sleep(500);
this.UpdateLayout();
this.InvalidateVisual();
MuzzleFlash.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

I tried those two intermediate lines as they supposedly forced windows to update, but all this did was pause for half a second without changing any sort of rectangles.

So I heard about BackgroundWorkers and how they're what I should use. After some brief reading, I came up with this. Note that Shoot is subscribed to a MouseDown event on a Canvas, which worked previously:

```
private void Shoot(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        BackgroundWorker UIUpdater = new BackgroundWorker();
        UIUpdater.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        UIUpdater.WorkerReportsProgress = false;

        UIUpdater.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(UI_DoWork);
        UIUpdater.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(cancelUIUpdate);

    }

    private void UI_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        MuzzleFlash.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        this.UpdateLayout();
        this.InvalidateVisual();
        MuzzleFlash.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void cancelUIUpdate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        bw.CancelAsync();
    }
```

Now it doesn't even pause for half a second, indicating to me that the worker isn't doing anything. How can I fix this, and make the rectangle appear/disappear?

Comment: I would use a timer.  You are not really doing work.

Comment: It doesn't work because you are doing everything in the worker thread. Main UI thread says *"Start a background worker, then end"*, while bg worker says *"set visible flag true, wait some time, set visible flag false, then end back to UI thread so UI can update"*. Note that the bg thread never sends a notification back to the main UI thread to update the display. If you want to do it this way, I'd suggest looking into WPF's Dispatcher. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15930792/302677) for a brief summary that uses a similar example to what you are looking to do here.

Comment: A simple "solution" would be to move your `MuzzleFlash.Visibility = Visibility.Visible` line to your main UI thread to execute from within the `Shoot(...)` method. Then code says *"set visible flag true, start a bg worker, then end and update display"*, while bg worker says *"wait some time, set visible flag false, then end back to UI thread so it can update"*. Also, you might want to put the *"set visible flag false"* bit in the RunWorkerCompleted because WPF doesn't usually update objects on threads that they weren't created on, so you may get an exception trying to update from a bg worker.

Comment: @Rachel thank you, I got it to work this way. Perhaps it might be better to use an animation in XAML, though?

I don't know much about SE etiquette so unsure which answer I should pick

Comment: You can accept whichever one you think is best for you :) Personally I thought [Himansh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39731850) to be the closest thing to match my comment and maintain your current code, however it lacked any kind of explanation which is really not what we like to see in answers. I liked [LoopedCode's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39731858) much better for what you are doing, even though it doesn't answer your specific question about the background worker usage. Sometimes alternate suggestions are a better solution than an answer to the exact question asked. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is bad idea to use background worker to manage animation in wpf. Animation should run from Storyboard. It can be specified through xaml or in code.

Your question of animating a rectangle is very simple with xaml:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="MuzzleFlash" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red">
    <Rectangle.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0.5"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>
```

For more complex animations, you can use Blend to design them interactively.

Updated response after comments:
If you want to make appear and disappear, you have to manipulate it from a parent container, as once rectangle hidden, it won't respond to mouse events.

You can put the rectangle in a grid and reference it by name to change its visibility in animation.

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0.0"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="MuzzleFlash">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}" />
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
    <Rectangle x:Name="MuzzleFlash" Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red">

    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How do I trigger it then? Does loaded literally just mean 'on load' or can I call it from code?

Comment: How do you want to trigger it? The example here uses Loaded just as example. You can trigger it for any event. Why do you think you need it trigger it from code?

Comment: Well, I essentially want to have it so when I click the rectangle shows for half a second and then disappears again. I set the event to MouseDown and the Visibility to Hidden by default (so x:Static Visibility.Visible in the storyboard) but it doesn't work (no response). I think I got some response before when I had it as MouseDown but visible by default, and therefore hiding instead.

Comment: If you set it Hidden, it is not HitTestVisible as such won't respond to mouse events. You want to manipulate it through a parent container. See updated example.

Comment: Ah right. Thanks for the help. I already have a solution, and I don't see any point changing it for quality reasons (I'm like 3 weeks into a c# course) - however, it is the best answer for anyone searching for this topic, so I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you make use off MVVm and you are binding to your viewmodel then give this a try

Bind a visibility converter to the rectangle and only show it when the value is something like true and false?

then in the background worker you set the value before and after the time

https://www.rhyous.com/2011/02/22/binding-visibility-to-a-bool-value-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

```
    private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Background Worker code///
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.ProgressChanged += bw_ProgressChanged;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        //Progress Bar Window
        grdProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //something to do
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Progress Bar Window close
        grdProgress.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        prg.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }


  bw.ReportProgress(value);
```

Comment: In addition to providing code, please explain why your answer works.