# WPF Datatrigger and UI dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

I am updating a property value with in a method call multiple times. 
My UI elements are bound to data properties and my viewModel has INotifyPropertychnaged implemented.
I have data triggers set to update UI values. It works fine for the final property value at the end of the method call. However, I want to refresh UI based on property value change within method call. What is the best way to do it?

Code Behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
OrderViewModel model = this.DataContext as OrderViewModel;
model.OrderStatus = OrderViewModel.OrderStatuses.Updating;

// Processing order logic 
// takes about few seconds, Here I want to update UI with Refreshing Icon inprogress.gif

model.OrderStatus = OrderViewModel.OrderStatuses.Updated;

}
```

XAML Code:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="NotCreatedSource" UriSource="/Images/notcreated_20x20.png" />

        <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="OrderLineItem">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource NotCreatedSource}" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="32" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="24" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Updated">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/checkmark_icon.png" ></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderStatus, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Updating">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Images/inprogress.gif" ></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="12,100,30,0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image Style="{StaticResource OrderLineItem}" Name="ConnectionImage" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button Width="250" Height="25" Margin="20" Click="Button_Click">Change status</Button>

    </StackPanel>
```

Model Class:

```
public class OrderViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public OrderStatuses OrderStatus 
        {
            get
            {
                return _orderstatus;
            }
            set
            {
                _orderstatus = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("OrderStatus");
            }
        }
        private OrderStatuses _orderstatus;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public enum OrderStatuses
        {
            Updated = 1,
            Updating,
            NotCreated,
            Failed,
            NotAvailable
        }
    }
```

and in UI based on those 2 statuses I have Image icons next to order Control. It never shows Icon for Updating, But at the end of call it shows updated.

How do I show both statuses update on UI?

Comment: Can't you move the logic to viewmodel so that it will be more clear to understand..use commands in viewmodel and view for this

Comment: Which logic are you recommending to move to viewmodel? My need is to refresh UI elements (Images) during the processing.

Comment: All your code runs at the same priority, and it all gets executed before any code to redraw the UI gets run. What you need is to break it up. Set OrderStatus to Updating, start a task to run your process, let the UI update, then once task finishes set OrderStatus to Updated and let UI update again. Usually I either use the Dispatcher or the Task Parallel Library for things like this. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926743/threading-and-collections-modification-in-wpf-c-sharp/15930792#15930792) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're blocking the UI thread for processing and WPF won't render. The hackiest workaround is like the old `Application.DoEvents` in VB6: periodically call `this.Dispatcher.Invoke` with a no-op delegate during the processing.

Slightly better--but still sidestepping the core issue--is to wrap the processing and final update in a delegate passed to `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`. This is a somewhat hacky continuation.

A logically clean way is to move the processing to the background via a Task (or thread or BackgroundWorker or any other async API) and complete the status update in a task continuation.

```
OrderViewModel model = this.DataContext as OrderViewModel;
model.OrderStatus = OrderViewModel.OrderStatuses.Updating;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => /* processing order logic */)
    .ContinueWith(t => model.OrderStatus = OrderViewModel.OrderStatuses.Updated);
```

Depending on your .NET Framework version, you can use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`.